# Opsworks HAProxy HTTPS redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, chef-infra, haproxy, aws-opsworks

I'm having trouble getting HAProxy to permanently redirect all requests to HTTP to HTTPS.

I have installed the standard Opsworks HAProxy configuration Chef recipe as a custom recipe and tried to modify it to redirect requests. I haven't succeeded though.

Can somebody help me with the modification?

Here is the default config recipe: https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/haproxy/templates/default/haproxy.cfg.erb

There are 4 domains/subdomains and they should all just be forced to HTTPS.

- app.domain.com
- api.domain.com
- app.domain2.com
- api.domain2.com

I have tried the following:

- Changed the frontend http-in default_backend to the HTTPS backend. It gave me several of these errors `ignored for backend 'php_app_servers_ssl Unable to use proxy 'php_app_servers_ssl' with wrong mode, required: http, has: tcp.' as it requires HTTP mode`. This error was in the deployment log.
- Change frontend https-in mode to http (to resolve the previous error). The deployment worked but gave a 400 Bad request on HTTP and `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` in browser on HTTPS.
- Added `redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }` in frontend http-in, which gave this error `'redirect' expects 'code', 'prefix', 'location', 'set-cookie', 'clear-cookie', 'drop-query' or 'append-slash' (was 'scheme').` possibly due to version of HAProxy. 'redirect' requires version 1.5 or higher (I believe).
- Added `redirect prefix https://app.domain.com if is_http { hdr(host) -i app.domain.com }`, which  gave me this error in deployment log: `'redirect': error detected while parsing redirect condition.`
- Corrected the redirect from above (which was wrong to address) and the deployment succeeded, but browser now again returns 400 Bad request on HTTP and `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` on HTTPS.

I don't have anymore ideas on what to try. Can somebody help me make the needed corrections to the config file?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of haproxy?   Also include your haproxy.conf in the question.